# add index on jsonb field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I need to search over the values of an array key of jsonb field in Postgres.

```
field: {'array_key' : [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Is it possible to add index on `array_key` or is there any optimized method to search over the values ?

search query will be something like

```
select * where field['array_key'].include?(2)
```

Comment: can you add how your search query would look like?

Comment: sure.. something like,  select * where field['array_key'].includes?(2)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create index on jsonb keys as,

```
add_index :table_name, :field, :using => :gin, :expression => "(field->'array_key')", :name => 'index_table_name_on_field_array_keys'
```

Then, you can search over indexed keys as,

```
where("table_name.field->'array_keys' @> ?", Array(2))
```

Comment: What version of rails does this require? I'm running 4.2.1 and get: `An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
Unknown key: :expression`

Comment: Ah, I see this is new to rails 5.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes

Comment: `add_index :table_name,  "(field->'array_key')", using: :gin, name: 'index_table_name_on_field_array_keys'` in Rails 5.0.0

Comment: How do you do this in rails 4? i.e. Lovely that we have it in Rails 5, but is there a way to hack this index creation in Rails 4 since it's not actually doing anything much other than the migration and the index is dealt with on the postgres side?

Comment: In Rails 4 I think the way to go is to write a raw SQL in both `up` and `down`.

Comment: For rails 4.2, I found this article helpful: https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I got the same error `Unknown key: :expression` for Rails 5.0.2. What version do I need to upgrade to?

Answer (score 7):

given that you have a 'pictures' table with a 'metadata' jsonb column

```
add_index(
  :pictures,
  "(metadata->>'Year')",
  name: "index_pictures_on_metadata_year"
)
```

should output something like

```
CREATE  INDEX  "index_pictures_on_metadata_year" ON "pictures"  ((metadata->>'Year'))
```

Comment: This solution for rails 5 created index for btree and ((metadata->>'Year'::text)) In query postgres use Sec Scan instead Index Scan