# Unknown key: :expression. Valid keys are: :unique, :order, :name, :where, :length, :internal, :using, :algorithm, :type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I'm trying to create a gin index on the table users on the jsonb column groups. On the hash key group_id. I'm using rails 5.0.2. Postgres 9.6. Please help.

```
add_index :users, :groups, :using => :gin, :expression => "(groups->>'group_id')", :name => 'group_id_index'
```

I got the idea from [add index on jsonb field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041821/add-index-on-jsonb-field)

Comment: In rails 5, the syntax seems to be different than you have (see the comments in the Q&A you linked to).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from the comments in the Q&A you linked to:

> add_index :table_name, "(field->'array_key')", using: :gin, name: 'index_table_name_on_field_array_keys' in Rails 5.0.0

It looks like you're not using the correct syntax for your rails version.